# How can i refresh a view every time when a tab bar item is clicked?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am making an application with TabBar. But TabBarController is not RootViewController. In the Tab Bar there are 4 tabs. One of those tabs is history which is linked with a table view which shows history. I want to refresh that view every time when i click that so that i can get updated tableview. How can i do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

use `- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` to update any content in your view.

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   // You code here to update the view.
}
```

This method will be called every time the view is about to be displayed.

Comment: it does not go to viewWillAppear of HistoryView when i click on history tab.

Comment: Yes, this methods will be called when using tabbars and navigation controllers.

Comment: I debugged it and i put some logs as well. Believe me its not going there.

Comment: Sorry to say, just test it and it gets called every time, you did add the `- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated ` to the `UIViewController` and not the `UIView`

Comment: this is my .h @interface RunListViewController : UITableViewController  and then in .m i have -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated in which i wrote this line of code [tableView reload] after [super viewWillAppear:animated]; anything wrong with this?

Comment: its not working. even i made an new view and tried it. not working there as well. its not navigational based application. are you sure that viewWillAppear is called when we click on tab?

Comment: Yes i'm sure, just tested it in one of my apps which does not use any `UINavigationController` just an `UITabbarController` and it works.

Comment: my app is a view based app. It has round about 10 views and in one view i have UITabBarController. and then different view are attached with that UITabBarController. does this make any difference to that viewWillAppear functions of views which are attached with UITabBarController?

Answer (score 1):

below code added plz ^^

If you change a tabBarIndex, At the same time -(void)viewWillAppear called.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // force the tableview to load
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

refer a Apple Sample Code: that is amazing great tutorial for you about UITabBarController
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TheElements/Introduction/Intro.html

Apple Sample Code is no added [super viewWillAppear:animated];

Comment: infact my question was where to call this function? i searched but couldn't find that when a tabbar item is clicked which function of that view is called.

Comment: not working. it does not go to viewWillAppear when i click on history tab.

Comment: don't forget to add `[super viewWillAppear:animated];` to the method.

Comment: - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"in viewWillAppear");
 //Reload the table view to indicate if a run gets posted
   [self.theTableView reloadData];
}

Comment: and i can not see that log "in viewWillAppear". and theTableView is not reloaded. I created a button and on that button's click i use same reloaded code and its working

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];
    if ([Globals sharedInstance].isFromFindSimiler)
    {
        [self.view addSubview:_findSimilerView];
        [_historyTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 85, 320, 490)];

    }
    else
    {

    [self history_webservice];
    }
}
```

I have achieved this. In this case, whenever user tabs on History screen I call web service for history and update tableview.

Answer (score 1):

instead of using `(void)ViewDidLoad` use `viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    //your code 
}
```